# Changing Data Output depending on pull down

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, onclick

I am new to coldfusion and Java Script and I can not figure the correct syntax needed to make this work. What I am trying to do is that there is a pull down menu that has three options; Active, Inactive, and All. The goal is that when the page originally loads that it defaults to active and shows all active shippers. However, if the user wants to see inactive user they would select it from the pull down and the data should change to only show those values. All would show both active and Inactive.

The way I thought to do this was to create a variable called Active_status and then use Onclick to change the value and refresh the page. I am using if statements to generate the data.

```
<cfparam name="active_status" default="ACTIVE">
```

This is at the beginning to show active first

```
 <select name="active_status" id="active_status" class="tx" onchange="editTable(this.value)">
        <option value="ACTIVE" selected="selected">ACTIVE</option>
        <option value="INACTIVE">INACTIVE</option>
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select>
```

This is the code to generate the options within the page

```
 <script language="javascript">
function editTable( inVal )
{
    if( inVal == 'ACTIVE' )
    {
        document.getElementById( "active_status" ).value = "ACTIVE";
        window.location.reload();
    }
    else if ( inVal == 'INACTIVE' )
    {
        document.getElementById( "active_status" ).value = "INACTIVE";
        window.location.reload();

    }
    else if ( inVal == 'ALL' )
    {
        document.getElementById( "active_status" ).value = "ALL";
        window.location.reload();

    }
}
 </script>
```

Show the active works but after each selection only active shows. I am sure it is due to the default I have but I am not sure of the correct syntax I need to make this work.

If you can assist me on this that would be greatly appreciated. Any advice would be great or if you have a better way to do this I am always eager to learn new things.

I made the change but it still is not changing when Inactive is clicked?

Comment: I don't see any ID's called `active_status`, just names. Did you mean to give your select the id active_status?

Comment: No worries, let me know if it fixes it or helps!

Comment: Is the problem that your select drop-down is always selecting "ACTIVE"?  If so, that is because you are setting it every time the page loads with `selected="selected"`. You need to check for the value and dynamically set the selected option when the page reloads.

Comment: Perhaps there is more to it... but this seems like an over-complication. Just submit the form when the selection changes, ie `onChange="this.form.submit"`. That will refresh the page and the selected value will be sent in `URL.active_status` (GET) or `FORM.active_status` (POST). Just be sure to scope your `cfparam` variable name as well.

Comment: @Leigh's suggestion regarding using onChange to submit the form does not work very well for people like me who use their keyboards more often than their mouse.  So, if you want your programs to work for all users, don't do it.

Comment: @DanBracuk - The original code already uses `onChange`, so it is not clear if that is a requirement of theirs. My suggestion is start with a simple modification that allows the existing code to work as intended. Then go from there. ie Get it working, then improve it. If you have a working example of the improvements you suggested, I am sure it would help the OP to see it.

Answer (score 1):

> The way I thought to do this was to create a variable called Active_status and then use Onclick to change the value and refresh the page.

By refreshing the page with Javascript without making any AJAX calls or submitting the form first, you are simply reloading the page and resetting the client-side form data. The data goes nowhere-- nothing is sent to the server.

If you want to dynamically change what is displayed using Coldfusion, then you must make an HTTP request to a Coldfusion page. You could do this various ways, but the simplest method is to use a form submission. In order to submit a form with HTML, your form needs three things:

1. A url to send the data to (your .cfm page), which goes in the form `action` attribute.
2. The HTTP method to use, which goes in the form `method` attribute. Typically, you'd use `POST`.
3. An `input` tag with `type="submit"`. This is the submit button that the user can click to submit the form.

Example:

```
<form action="myPage.cfm" method="POST">
   <!-- ...form fields go here... -->

   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When a form is submitted to a Coldfusion page using `action="POST"`, the Coldfusion code within that page can then access the submitted form data by using the `form` scope. For instance, you would use `form.active_status` to get the data from the "active_status" drop-down in your example.

You can then use this information to dynamically determine what to display on the page. Example .cfm page:

```
<cfif form.active_status is 'ACTIVE'>    
    <div>Status is active</div>
<cfelse>    
    <div>Status is not active</div>
</cfif>
```

Side note: You cannot interact with Coldfusion directly using Javascript. They are executed in two different environments on two separate machines: JS is in the browser on the client, and CF is in the JVM on the server.

Comment: (Edit/fix typo): *Typically, you'd use POST* Depends on the purpose of the form. (The OP does not make that clear) If it is simply used to retrieve data, like a search form, then `GET` is more typical. However, if it is used to make modifications to server data, such as an "edit" form, then `POST` is more appropriate.